# How to return Yes or No in SQL without if/case flows

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, enums, case

Apart from the IFs and the CASEs from SQL, is there another way to return a table of "Yes"/"No" (in SQL)?

EDIT: Yes, it's bad practice, and no I can't do so in the application (it's a school project with specific requirements)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? I mean what is your real requirement that has lead you to ask the question?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question.  Are you looking to return all values that contain a yes or no? Or did you want to assign yes or no values depending on another value in the table?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 ID, 'YES' as Option NION ALL SELECT 2, 'No') YesNo` Adding a U to nion all so it is `UNION ALL`  stupid firewall causing issues with me doing it and won't let me post.  you could join to the table if you need to translate values then (Say 1 yes 2 no...)

Comment: The database I'm working on is given, and the query returns no result.
This lack of results should be returned as "No", not as "0", which is something we must achieve without using cases and ifs, as said above.

Comment: Do this in the application, not in sql.

Comment: Show us the query, the current and expected result. Looks like this is the job for `LEFT JOIN` and/or `COALESCE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea would be the use of UNION between two selects, one with 'yes' and one with 'no'.
But the above answers are enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following is bad practice:

You can have a column that has the string values "Yes" and "No" and then just select from that column.

You will then have to maintain this columns values.

A better practice would be:

Have a bit column and then in the selects against that column have a case statement to return string values.

Answer (score 0):

use an inline view to translate 0 to `'No'` and and 1 to `'Yes'`, though you could just stop at no.

```
SELECT yesNo.Option
FROM YourTable A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 1 ID, 'YES' as Option UNION ALL SELECT 0, 'No') YesNo
 on A.Field1 = yesNo.ID
```

This assumes that 0 is in the results of mytable somewhere.

1. Field1 should be the the column name having 0 or 1 or whatever in it you need to translate
2. yourTable should be just that the table in question (or query)
3. All this does is create an inline view with a list of hard coded translations.  Better would be to have a translation table and simply use it.